# continuity of $f(t,u(t))$ with respect to $t$

Tags: calculus

My question relates to definition of continuity from calculus.

Let $y=f(t,u(t))$. What does it mean $f$ is continuous with respect to $t$ at $t_{0}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the definition $y=f(t,u(t))$ is not related to your question. And it seems that $t$ is the first parameter of the function $f$.

The function $f$ is continuous with respect to $t$ at $t_0$ if
$$\lim_{t\to t_0} f(t,x) = f(t_0, x)$$
for any $x$ such that there is a neighborhood of $(t_0,x)$ where $f$ is defined.

Comment: shouldn't the fact that $u$ is a function of $t$ be somehow reflected in this definition?

Comment: $u$ is not part of the definition of $f$ is it @ZviadKhukhunashvili? It would be different if we want to know about the continuity of $y$ with respect to $t$. Then $u$ would be involved.

Comment: what do you mean by "not part of the definition of $f$"?  $u$ is unknown function, $f$ is known.

Comment: @ZviadKhukhunashvili, we could have for instance $f(t,x)=t+x$ and $u(t)=\sqrt t$. Note that the definition of $f$ does not contain any reference to $u$, nor does its continuity depend on it. However, we have $y(t)=f(t,u(t))=t+\sqrt t$, so the continuity of $y$ does depend on $u$.

Comment: then I say $f(t,u(t))$ is the right hand side of an ODE with unknown $u(t)$ and I need to check whether it satisfies conditions of the existence and uniqueness theorem, in particular, continuity of $f$ in $t$.  Should I go with the first way or the second way?

Comment: @ZviadKhukhunashvili, if you have $u'(t)=f(t,u(t))$, then there exists a unique solution around $t_0$ if $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in its second parameter (let's call it $x$), and continuous in its first parameter $t$.

Comment: that is what I am trying to check.  So do I treat $u(t)$ as fixed and consider the limit above to check for continuity in $t$?

Comment: @ZviadKhukhunashvili, yes, that is half of the check you need to make. For the other half we treat $t$ as fixed, and check uniform Lipschitz continuity with respect to the second parameter $x$.